# jQuery UI button function doesn't work on checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the [jQueryUI button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) widget, especially the option to turn checkbox into nice buttons.

The normal button works fine, but the checkbox doesn't!

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<label for="input">
    <input id="input" type="checkbox"/>Checkbox
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#button').button();
$('#input').button();
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work on checkbox!!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cY7fe/)

Comment: Where is the documentation that says you can turn a checkbox into a button?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko it's in the second paragraph of the Overview section from the link provided by OP :)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution:**
Change html to:

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<label for="input">
    Checkbox
</label>
<input id="input" type="checkbox"/>
```

And it will work properly, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cY7fe/1/).

**Explanation:**
If you check the jQuery-UI code, especially the function **_determineButtonType** (line 7069 on version 1.8.18) you will find

```
var ancestor = this.element.parents().filter(":last"),
            labelSelector = "label[for='" + this.element.attr("id") + "']";
this.buttonElement = ancestor.find( labelSelector );
```

So jQuery-UI assumes that it can find the label within the **last parent** of the input, while in your example, the label **is** the last parent.
I think this is a bug that should be fixed, because many developers have the habbit to write the label just like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<label for="input">Checkbox</label>
<input id="input" type="checkbox"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cY7fe/2/

The checkbox should'nt have been within the label, but rather next to it. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks, seen skafandri's explanation?

Comment: Why yes I have. Quite thorough, he deserves the 'answer' points